# JEB pro is not showing xrefs for native code (arm)

Tags: debugging, android, arm, shared-object, jeb

i have this problem when analyzing arm shared object.
when working with IDA pro, it finds all xrefs but in jeb, most of xrefs are missing.

when JEB finfishes, the final analysis lacks most of xrefs. I gave JEB 9GB of ram too.
[image]

[image]

i still cant find out whats wrong.
maybe i should enable something in the Options?!

Comment: I recommend asking in the Jeb google group or in their slack channel (links to both are on the Jeb website under "Support")

Comment: i tried the Google group and got no answers. will try these too, thanks.